# window.onclick not working for the first click

Tags: javascript, asp.net, model-view-controller, onclick, asp.net-ajax

I am using   window.onclick = function (e) {} in my ajax success function it is working but on the second click not on the first click. I have tried several solutions like changing the window.onlclick to window.addEventListener("click", function(event) {}); ...etc but they are not working
here is my code

```
function URLfunction(id) {

    var value = id.id;
    var PageID = value;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Admin/RedirectToURL",
        data: { id: PageID },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (result) {

            window.onclick = function (e) {
                if (e.ctrlKey==true) {
                    window.open(result.Url);
                }
                else {
                    window.location.href = result.Url;

                }
            }

        }
    });
}
```

**Thanks in advance**

Comment: Are you waiting for the ajax call to complete before clicking?

Comment: probably you are hitting before js execution reaches success function.

Comment: Does the first click not invoke this URLFunction?

Comment: Is the first click the one that triggered the Ajax call?? If yes, then that is impossible since the click has finished before you even bound the event. You would need to just call the code inside the success method, but most likely pop up blockers would block the window.open action.

Comment: @epascarello Thankyou got it